# how do I change the fontsize in custom_radio_grouped_button package on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

how do I change the fontsize in custom_radio_grouped_button package on flutter?

package:
https://pub.dev/packages/custom_radio_grouped_button#-readme-tab-

[image]

```
  Widget _selectDayBar() {
    return CustomCheckBoxGroup(
      buttonColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
      buttonLables: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
      buttonValuesList: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
      checkBoxButtonValues: (values) => print(values),
      defaultSelected: "Mon",
      horizontal: false,
      hight: 100,
      width: 50,
      selectedColor: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
      // padding: 10,
      customShape: CircleBorder(
        // borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
        side: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor)
      ),
      enableShape: true,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **customise package** according to your requirements.

You can hold **ctrl(command) key and click on widget**, which take you to the implementation of widget. Now find out **Text widget** in it and **change size** (default size in this package is **15**) according to your requirements.

Moreover, if you want to add **fontSize** property then you can also add this in package. i only suggest to do this if you want to change font size more than once in same project.

Make sure that you do **full restart your app** because it does not reflect in hot reload.

Comment: Yes, I did tried this but it didn't work. It works after I restart the app. I didn't know I need to restart it. thanks!

Comment: Yes, you require full restart to reflect the change. Accept the answer if you got your desire rest.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Simply go to that package and copy the source code into your own source code and change values as you wish.

[Here](https://github.com/ketanchoyal/custom_radio_grouped_button/blob/master/lib/CustomButtons/CustomCheckBoxGroup.dart) is the full source code of `CustomCheckBoxGroup`